# Can rosserial set parameters?

Tags: ros, rosserial-arduino, rosserial, parameter, parameter-server

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [rosserial parameter](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial/Overview/Parameters) documentation shows getting parameters from the parameter server, but not setting parameters. Is there a way to set parameters from rosserial?

I'm guessing not, since the [`NodeHandle` class](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/blob/46a7d8be2af4a5fae0f9c324369eab31394c0d4e/rosserial_client/src/ros_lib/ros/node_handle.h) only has parameter getters, not setters, but I'm wondering if anything's in the works or why this hasn't been a priority yet.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256519/can-rosserial-set-parameters?/) by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on ROS Answers with karma: 539 on 2017-03-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-03-08**:
Parameters are usually set during startup/launch, and aren't normally used to communicate information from hardware to other nodes, so that's probably why there hasn't been an effort to set parameters from rosserial.

**Comment by [nckswt](https://answers.ros.org/users/3362/nckswt/) on 2017-03-08**:
I was looking for a good way to provide several 32-byte constant values from my microcontroller into my ROS environment (unique IDs for all my devices, read on boot). `rosserial` doesn't seem to have a latching mechanism, so I supposed my best option is to use service calls through `rosserial`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There isn't an enumeration in the TopicInfo message for setting parameters: https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/blob/jade-devel/rosserial_msgs/msg/TopicInfo.msg , and this is the message type that defines the wire protocol for seting up topics and services and retrieving parameters, so the definitive answer is no; rosserial cannot set parameters.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1